# Spring Boot 404 not found error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to run the spring boot application but getting the 404 not found error.

Project structure:

```
src/
 +- main/
     +- java/
     |   + com/
         |   + demo/
             |    SpringBootDemo.java
             |    + controller/
                  |    HomeController.java
     +- resources/
             |   application.yml


src/
 +- main/
     +- webapp/
        +- WEB-INF/
           +- pages/
              | home.jsp
```

HomeController.java

```
package com.demo.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String getHome() {
        System.out.println("Controller");
        return "home";
    }
}
```

application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8080
spring:
  mvc:
    view:
      prefix: /WEB-INF/pages/
      suffix: .jsp
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.6.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = 'com.demo.SpringBootDemo'

version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

// In this section you declare where to find the dependencies of your project
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent')
    compile('javax.servlet.jsp.jstl:javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api')
}

jar {
  manifest {
    attributes(
      'Main-Class': 'com.demo.SpringBootDemo'
    )
  }
}
```

SpringBootDemo.java

```
package com.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages="com.demo")
public class SpringBootDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootDemo.class, args);
    }    
}
```

home.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
    Hello World
</body>
</html>
```

When I try to execute the code, it shows in the output as

```
Controller
```

But it gives the `Whitelabel Error Page` when I visit http://localhost:8080/

Comment: Have you read this? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jsp-limitations How do you build and run your application? I see no war plugin being applied to your gradle build, so you probably ignored this important warning from the documentation.`

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**
Ok I'll try to do better. It was not my intention to do you wrong...

I think you need to extend the SpringBootApplication class from  `SpringBootServletInitializer` to get servlet functionality in your Spring Boot application

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class WebApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(WebApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

In order to be able to resolve the view you have to define these properties:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/pages
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

or of course the `yaml` variant of them. The actual jsp pages need then be placed in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/pages

These are the dependencies in my pom

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I hope you can translate this to gradle yourself?

My sample controller looks like this:

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String hello(Model model, @RequestParam(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name) {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you with getting your app working...

Comment: This link gives the tutorial about REST web service, but I stuck in the problem of web application. This link doesn't give the answer as I already searched for the tutorial but still stuck in the issue. Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: Sorry guys it was not my intention to give a bad answer. Hope this one will do better...

Comment: After adding `compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")` in the build.gradle file and placing home.html in the resource/templates folder, I got it working.

Comment: ALso might be helpful to change scope of tomcat-embed-jasper dependency from <scope>provided</scope> to <scope>compile</scope>. Works for me!

Answer (score 1):

Run with maven spring boot goal:  `spring-boot:run`

Steps to setup maven configuration in IntelliJ:

Debug/Run Configuration | Click on + button visible at top left | Select Maven | Set command line to `spring-boot:run`